# OpenCv Camera does'nt work on all OS versions

Tags: android, opencv

I was working on a FaceRecognition Project, try to learn a little bit about OpenCv, I downloaded two github projects, when runing them, they work fine on my device Android 5.1.1, one of them shows back camera only but works fine, the other one shows front camera but app crashes mostely.

I tried them on an Android 7.1.1, the one of back camera didn't work at all! the camera dosn't show and app crashes, and the other one of front camera works but the calibration of camera is very very and very bad!

I don't know what is the problem with the versions of android.

Here are the two github projects that i was trying:

Front Camera:

https://github.com/assemmohamedali/OpenCVFaceRecogonition

this is the logcat of the crash app error:

```
 Caused by: CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.0.0-pre) E:\AssemCourses\opencv-master\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:235: error: (-215:Assertion failed) s >= 0 in function 'setSize'
```

- The Camera view on Android 7.1.1 was like zoomed in and not clear!

Back Camera only:
https://github.com/abhn/marvel

What is the problem? is it the OpenCv Version?

Thank you guys in Advance

Comment: What is the crash they are throwing? Post logcat

Comment: I updated my question, please check it

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest you to Go for Firebase Machine Learning KIT instead of OpenCV for Face Detection as it is quite simpler than that. You can have [full Playlist of ML Kit Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uTl5iS9XEhg&list=PLXjF1ATee10U_VqxUIAw13aV9wiIkGnXb)

Coming Soon.. Live Face Detection along with facial elements.

Comment: Is there any sample of code in github about Face detection and identification using ML kit?

Comment: Just ping me on mgouravsharma21@gmail.com, i will provide you the full healthy code.

Kindly Vote up if it really helps for you.